# What if I add new node at non leaf node in binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

What should be the behavior..?

1. As we are adding to non leaf node, so it should update that node and keep children nodes.

or

2. Update non leaf node and discard children as we are adding and not updating.

or

3. Operation itself is invalid.

Comment: A binary tree for what? Without specifying that, the question has not much sense

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the tree insertion logic. You add a node to a tree, the tree determines if it ends up being a leaf node or an intermediate node. You've tagged your question binary-tree and binary-search-tree. This would be my code for adding a node to a binary search tree.

```
def add(self, root, item):
  if root is None:
    return
  if item < root.data:
    root.left = add(self, root.left, item)
  else:
    root.right = add(self, root.right, item)
 return root
```

Ofcourse this tree does not cater to duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It just depends on your binary tree.

There are two main forms. The first is the canonical binary tree with "left" and "right" children. If you specify that a node shall have two children or none, you can't easily insert extra parents. You need a dummy sibling for the grandchild you have just created. if you relax that rule, you can easily enough insert a new parent between node and its old parent.

The other form is the anary tree as a binary tree. This has "child" and "next" pointers. So in binary form its the same as the canonical tree, but the meaning is different and you draw it differently.  Now of course we have to specify whehter we are inserting an extra sibling (the next pointer) or an extra child (the child pointer). But typically you specify that the node you insert shall not itself have any siblings (next pointer is null). it can also of course have a null child.

Answer (score 0):

> As we are adding to non leaf node, so it should update that node and keep children nodes.

That would actually mean REPLACING not adding IMHO. Note that, though perfectly fine to do that with BT; in case of BST, it would possibly trigger restructuring of the BST itself!

> Update non leaf node and discard children as we are adding and not updating.

I would say that would be OVERKILL in the name of adding. 
Think of a case when you have price of items stored in tree nodes. If you ADD price of a new item, should that lead to the destruction of old data? Perhaps no!

> Operation itself is invalid.

Addition can't be invalid scenario here, as there is no prerequisite to keep the binary tree as it is.

So, here the effect of addition should be purely scenario-based.